# How To Access Google speardsheet data using Zend Gdata

Tags: php, zend-framework

I used zend Gdata.following is my code.

```
    $user = "sample@gmail.com";
    $pass = "sample@123"$service = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass); 
    $spreadsheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);
    $feed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed();
```

I got

```
    Message: Authentication with Google failed. Reason: BadAuthentication
```

Could U help me How to get I Authontication to access Gdata?